# sql fine tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, with-statement, sql-tuning

> > In a Table, I need to combine 2 records into one record, based on columns
> >     (in this case column 1.WORK_ORDER_NUM, 2.ESN 3.PLANT 4. REMD_PART_NUM
> >     5. REMD_PART_SERIAL).  If these 5 columns are equal then I have to use Aggregate function in other column to make it into one record.[In
> >     this case the columns are LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,REMD_PART_TSN and
> >     REMD_PART_CSN].

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT decode (PLANT ,'ECL','CELMA','EDS','CELMA',PLANT)PLANT,
 COUNT(*) RECORD_COUNT,
 COUNT(DISTINCT OFF.REMD_PART_NUM) REMD_PART_NUM_COUNT,
 COUNT(DISTINCT OFF.REMD_PART_SERIAL) REMD_PART_SER_NUM_COUNT,
  COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'LL',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) LL_COUNT,
 COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'LR',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) LR_COUNT,
 COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'TR',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) TR_COUNT,
 SUM(OFF.REMD_PART_QTY) TOTAL_REMD_PART_QTY, 
  SUM(decode(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,null,0,
     CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_TSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
            THEN CAST(REMD_PART_TSN AS NUMBER)
        ELSE 0
    END
  )) TOTAL_TSN,
 SUM(decode(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,null,0,
    CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_CSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
            THEN CAST(REMD_PART_CSN AS NUMBER)
        ELSE 0
    END
 )) TOTAL_CSN
FROM (with t as ( SELECT distinct PLANT,
WORK_ORDER_NUM,ESN,REMD_PART_NUM,REMD_PART_SERIAL,REMD_PART_IIN,
LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,
REMD_PART_QTY,REMD_PART_TSN,REMD_PART_CSN,REMD_PART_TSO,REMD_PART_CSO
,REMD_PART_TSC,REMD_PART_CSC,REMD_CYCLE_REMAIN          
FROM <TABLE1> 
WHERE 
REMD_PART_NUM is not null 
)
select DISTINCT PLANT,WORK_ORDER_NUM,ESN,REMD_PART_NUM,REMD_PART_SERIAL 
,REMD_PART_IIN
 ,(select max(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND) from t bb  where aa.PLANT=bb.PLANT and 
aa.WORK_ORDER_NUM=bb.WORK_ORDER_NUM 
 and aa.ESN=bb.ESN 
  and aa.REMD_PART_NUM=bb.REMD_PART_NUM
  and aa.REMD_PART_SERIAL=bb.REMD_PART_SERIAL) LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND
 ,REMD_PART_QTY
 ,(select max(REMD_PART_TSN) from t bb  where aa.PLANT=bb.PLANT and 
aa.WORK_ORDER_NUM=bb.WORK_ORDER_NUM 
 and aa.ESN=bb.ESN 
 and aa.REMD_PART_NUM=bb.REMD_PART_NUM
 and aa.REMD_PART_SERIAL=bb.REMD_PART_SERIAL) REMD_PART_TSN
 ,
(select max(REMD_PART_CSN) from t bb  where aa.PLANT=bb.PLANT and             
aa.WORK_ORDER_NUM=bb.WORK_ORDER_NUM 
  and aa.ESN=bb.ESN 
  and aa.REMD_PART_NUM=bb.REMD_PART_NUM
  and aa.REMD_PART_SERIAL=bb.REMD_PART_SERIAL) REMD_PART_CSN
  from t aa) OFF
WHERE 
REMD_PART_NUM is not null
GROUP BY decode (PLANT ,'ECL','CELMA','EDS','CELMA',PLANT)
```

**And it takes around 8 hours to complete. Is there any other way to complete it faster.**
[It took 8 hours to complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJNTA.png)

Comment: Fine tuning? Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh It's Oracle.

Comment: It's Oracle. @jarlh

Comment: Look at the execution plan to determine where oracle is spending all its time working things out. ps; as far as queries go, it looks naaasty - queries that have a nested subquery between select and from always raise alarm bells for me. I think you might do better not by asking us to fix the query you wrote, but by giving us example inputs and output and asking for help to write a new query in a different way, to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a better formatting of the query, it will allow you to easily understand the code and notice repeated patterns:

```
SELECT decode (PLANT ,'ECL','CELMA','EDS','CELMA',PLANT)PLANT,
    COUNT(*) RECORD_COUNT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT OFF.REMD_PART_NUM) REMD_PART_NUM_COUNT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT OFF.REMD_PART_SERIAL) REMD_PART_SER_NUM_COUNT,
    COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'LL',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) LL_COUNT,
    COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'LR',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) LR_COUNT,
    COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'TR',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) TR_COUNT,
    SUM(OFF.REMD_PART_QTY) TOTAL_REMD_PART_QTY, 
    SUM(decode(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,null,0,
            CASE
                WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_TSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
                THEN CAST(REMD_PART_TSN AS NUMBER)
                ELSE 0
            END
        )) TOTAL_TSN,
    SUM(decode(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,null,0,
            CASE
                WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_CSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
                THEN CAST(REMD_PART_CSN AS NUMBER)
                ELSE 0
            END
        )) TOTAL_CSN
FROM (
    with t as ( 
        SELECT distinct PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM,ESN,REMD_PART_NUM,REMD_PART_SERIAL,REMD_PART_IIN,
                LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,
                REMD_PART_QTY,REMD_PART_TSN,REMD_PART_CSN,REMD_PART_TSO,REMD_PART_CSO
                ,REMD_PART_TSC,REMD_PART_CSC,REMD_CYCLE_REMAIN          
        FROM <TABLE1> 
        WHERE REMD_PART_NUM is not null 
    )
    select DISTINCT PLANT,WORK_ORDER_NUM,ESN,REMD_PART_NUM,REMD_PART_SERIAL 
            ,REMD_PART_IIN
            ,(  select max(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND) 
                from t bb  
                where aa.PLANT=bb.PLANT 
                    and aa.WORK_ORDER_NUM=bb.WORK_ORDER_NUM 
                    and aa.ESN=bb.ESN 
                    and aa.REMD_PART_NUM=bb.REMD_PART_NUM
                    and aa.REMD_PART_SERIAL=bb.REMD_PART_SERIAL
            ) LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND
            ,REMD_PART_QTY
            ,(  select max(REMD_PART_TSN) from t bb  
                where aa.PLANT=bb.PLANT 
                    and aa.WORK_ORDER_NUM=bb.WORK_ORDER_NUM 
                    and aa.ESN=bb.ESN 
                    and aa.REMD_PART_NUM=bb.REMD_PART_NUM
                    and aa.REMD_PART_SERIAL=bb.REMD_PART_SERIAL
            ) REMD_PART_TSN
            ,
            (   select max(REMD_PART_CSN) from t bb  
                where aa.PLANT=bb.PLANT 
                    and aa.WORK_ORDER_NUM=bb.WORK_ORDER_NUM 
                    and aa.ESN=bb.ESN 
                    and aa.REMD_PART_NUM=bb.REMD_PART_NUM
                    and aa.REMD_PART_SERIAL=bb.REMD_PART_SERIAL
            ) REMD_PART_CSN
    from t aa
) OFF
WHERE REMD_PART_NUM is not null
GROUP BY decode (PLANT ,'ECL','CELMA','EDS','CELMA',PLANT)
;
```

---

You will see that the below pattern is repeated 3 times (3 almost identical subqueries):

```
select max( some_field ) 
from t bb  
where aa.PLANT=bb.PLANT 
  and aa.WORK_ORDER_NUM=bb.WORK_ORDER_NUM 
  and aa.ESN=bb.ESN 
  and aa.REMD_PART_NUM=bb.REMD_PART_NUM
  and aa.REMD_PART_SERIAL=bb.REMD_PART_SERIAL
```

---

You will also easily see that there are 3 very expensive sort operations in this query - one DISTINCT in the innermost subquery, then another DISTINCT in another subquery, then finally GROUP BY operation (a kind of DISTINCT) in the top level query.

---

Looking only on your query one can easily eliminate one sort (DISTINCT) using analytic functions in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT PLANT,WORK_ORDER_NUM,ESN,REMD_PART_NUM,REMD_PART_SERIAL,
           REMD_PART_IIN, REMD_PART_QTY,
           max( LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND ) over 
              (partition by PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM, ESN, REMD_PART_NUM, REMD_PART_SERIAL) 
           as LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,
           max( REMD_PART_TSN )       over 
              (partition by PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM, ESN, REMD_PART_NUM, REMD_PART_SERIAL) 
           as REMD_PART_TSN,
           max( REMD_PART_CSN )       over 
              (partition by PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM, ESN, REMD_PART_NUM, REMD_PART_SERIAL) 
           as REMD_PART_CSN,
           row_number() over 
              (partition by PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM, ESN, REMD_PART_NUM, REMD_PART_SERIAL, REMD_PART_IIN, REMD_PART_QTY 
                   order by PLANT) as Rn
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE REMD_PART_NUM is not null 
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

so the final query migh be:

```
SELECT decode (PLANT ,'ECL','CELMA','EDS','CELMA',PLANT)PLANT,
    COUNT(*) RECORD_COUNT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT OFF.REMD_PART_NUM) REMD_PART_NUM_COUNT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT OFF.REMD_PART_SERIAL) REMD_PART_SER_NUM_COUNT,
    COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'LL',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) LL_COUNT,
    COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'LR',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) LR_COUNT,
    COUNT(DECODE(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,'TR',LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,NULL)) TR_COUNT,
    SUM(OFF.REMD_PART_QTY) TOTAL_REMD_PART_QTY, 
    SUM(decode(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,null,0,
            CASE
                WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_TSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
                THEN CAST(REMD_PART_TSN AS NUMBER)
                ELSE 0
            END
        )) TOTAL_TSN,
    SUM(decode(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,null,0,
            CASE
                WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_CSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
                THEN CAST(REMD_PART_CSN AS NUMBER)
                ELSE 0
            END
        )) TOTAL_CSN
FROM (
    SELECT PLANT,WORK_ORDER_NUM,ESN,REMD_PART_NUM,REMD_PART_SERIAL,REMD_PART_IIN, REMD_PART_QTY,
           max( LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND ) over (partition by PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM, ESN, REMD_PART_NUM, REMD_PART_SERIAL) as LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,
           max( REMD_PART_TSN )       over (partition by PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM, ESN, REMD_PART_NUM, REMD_PART_SERIAL) as REMD_PART_TSN,
           max( REMD_PART_CSN )       over (partition by PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM, ESN, REMD_PART_NUM, REMD_PART_SERIAL) as REMD_PART_CSN,
           row_number()               over (partition by PLANT, WORK_ORDER_NUM, ESN, REMD_PART_NUM, REMD_PART_SERIAL, REMD_PART_IIN, REMD_PART_QTY 
                                            order by PLANT) as Rn
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE REMD_PART_NUM is not null 
)
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY decode (PLANT ,'ECL','CELMA','EDS','CELMA',PLANT)
```

---

I feel that this query could be further optimized, but it would require insight into the structure of the tables and a knowledge of business requirements.

---

There are still some microoptimalizations possible, though.
This pattern:

```
SUM(decode(LLP_TRACKD_PART_IND,null,0,
        CASE
            WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_TSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
            THEN CAST(REMD_PART_TSN AS NUMBER)
            ELSE 0
        END
    )) TOTAL_TSN,
```

can be replaced with this one:

```
coalesce( 
    SUM( 
        CASE
            WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_TSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
            THEN CAST(REMD_PART_TSN AS NUMBER)
            ELSE 0
        END
    ), 0
)
```

since SUM ignores nulls, then checking for NULL value for each record is a waste. For a small number of records ( < 1 million) it does not matter, but for hundreds of millions of records you can achieve the effect of scale - say 0.05 ms for checking each record multiplied by 10.000.000 records can give 500 seconds.